# backbone click event not working in collection view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

i am very new to back bone,( Backbone.js 1.0.0) this is my sample html page where iam using views and model ,i have a button and text field,and every time   i click on that button ,i need to display  the content of the  text field to '<li> ' tag,this is my  html page

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Backbone Application</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text"  id="txt1">
    <button class="btn1">Save</button>
    </body>

    <script>
    var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({
           initialize: function(){
        console.log('car model created...');

     } ,
     defaults: {
         name: 'alto'

     }  
    });
    // A List of People
    var CarCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Car,
        initialize: function(){
        console.log('Car Collection created...');
      }

    });
    carView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'li',

        initialize: function() {
        console.log('Car view created...');
        },

        render: function( model ) {
               this.$el.html(this.model.get('name'));
               return this;  // returning this from render method..
            console.log('rendered')
        },

    });
    CarCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'ul',

        initialize: function() {
        console.log('Car Collection View created');
         this.collection.on("add", this.render, this);
        },
        events: {
             'click .btn1':'getcar'
           },
           getcar: function() {
               console.log('Artist model changed...'+$('.nameField').val());
               var car_name = $('#txt1').val();
               this.collection.add({name:car_name} );
           },
        render: function(){
            this.collection.each(function(car){
                var carView1= new carView({ model: car });
                this.$el.append(carView1.render().el); // calling render method manually..
            }, this);
            return this; // returning this for chaining..
        }

    });
    var carCollection = new CarCollection([
        {
            name: 'maruthi'
        }]);
    var carCollectionView = new CarCollectionView({ collection: carCollection });
    $(document.body).append(carCollectionView.render().el);
    </script>
    </html>
```

it was  working first time when i call the collection view ,but i  when i click the button,nothing happens,any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to first understand how events work in backbone.js views. When you specify an events hash in a view backbone delegates these events to the view's `el`. In your case since the button isn't a descendant of your collection view's el it's events aren't being triggered.

For example if your HTML and collection view were slightly modified your event should fire.

HTML

```
<div id="carCnt">
   <input type="text"  id="txt1">
    <button class="btn1">Save</button>
   <ul id="carList"></ul>
</div>
```

View

```
CarCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#carCnt',

        initialize: function() {
        console.log('Car Collection View created');
         this.collection.on("add", this.render, this);
        },
        events: {
             'click .btn1':'getcar'
           },
           getcar: function() {
               console.log('Artist model changed...'+$('.nameField').val());
               var car_name = $('#txt1').val();
               this.collection.add({name:car_name} );
           },
          render: function(){
     //clear list first
          this.$el.find('#carList').empty();
        this.collection.each(function(car){
            var carView1= new carView({ model: car });

          this.$el.find('#carList').append(carView1.render().el); // calling render method manually..
        }, this);
        return this; // returning this for chaining..
    }

    });
```

And here's a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/duluziju/1/)

This should get your current code working however in general you might want to render your collection view off of the DOM and attach it after it is rendered.